# ASM not reporting constant instructions

Tags: java, jvm, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

I'm trying to use the ASM library to read byte code and translate it into a different format. Starting off with a simple test class containing this method:

```
public static double square(double a) {
    return a * a;
}
```

Which compiles to this byte code:

```
public static double square(double);
Code:
   0: dload_0
   1: dload_0
   2: dmul
   3: dreturn
```

using this MethodVisitor to read the code:

```
    return new MethodVisitor(ASM7) {
        @Override
        public void visitInsn(int opcode) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%02x", opcode));
        }

        @Override
        public void visitLdcInsn(Object value) {
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    };
```

I get this output:

```
6b
af
```

Those are the opcodes for `dmul` and `dreturn` respectively, so it is traversing the code, but it's not reporting the `dload_0` instructions, either by `visitInsn` or `visitLdcInsn`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASM expands `dload_0` to `dload 0`. At the same time, when writing, ASM optimizes the byte code instruction back to the short-cut constant when writing it to a `ClassWriter`. Override `visitVarInsn` and you will see the output with the byte code as first and the variable index as second argument.

*(Edited after Holger's comment.)*

Comment: It seems that the OP thinks that the zero was a constant (as indicated by “constant instructions” in the title and in overriding `visitLdcInsn`), so it’s worth emphasizing that the zero is a *variable index*, not a constant, hence, `visitVarInsn` is the right choice. It seems you’ve been misled by the OP’s confusion when you wrote `visitIntInsn`. As a fun fact, constants pushing instructions, like `dconst_0`, are not expanded, but passed to `visitInsn(int opcode)`